# Specify path of savefig with pylab or matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am struggling on how to find the correct way to specify the save path (or repository) when calling the function savefig in matplotlib or pylab.

I tried several syntaxes, but everytime python console returns :

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../MyDocs/resource/frames/MyImage.png'

Currently, I have written the following :

```
pylab.savefig('../MyDocs/resource/frames/MyImage.png')
```

Does someone know how to do it?

Comment: either with       `pylab.savefig('~/MyDocs/resource/frames/MyImage.png')` or `pylab.savefig('~MyDocs/resource/frames/MyImage.png')` it doesnt work...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The tilde operator and the variable `$HOME` are entered as strings and therefore do not function while saving. You have to provide either relative path (as you did) or provide the full path. Eg. `pylab.savefig("/home/username/Desktop/myfig.png")`.

Comment: Actually, the simpler, the better... I should have tried it first. Thanks! (I used the full path solution)

Comment: what if i have several figures to write, and i need to name them according to the name of csv file, from where i took my data?

Comment: @Polly then you should do string comprehension: read the name of the csv file, and then use sth like `foo = path + "csv_filename"` and then save your figure with `pylab.savefig(foo)`. In this case `path` is `"home/username/"` . Hope it helps

Answer (score 6):

For matplotlib.pyplot, the error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` can occur due to nonexistence of the containing folder `../MyDocs/resource/frames/`.
So maybe first create the folder

```py
import os
os.makedirs('../MyDocs/resource/frames/')
```

then rerun the savefig function.